# How to build custom Windows Phone interface

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I want to build up the interface of my app to be similar like a [Material](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html) app.

This is definitely possible because there is an app outside already which try to follow the Material guidelines. Here is a little animated gif about it:

[image: animation showing the app]

The two main thing I want to archive is

- the navigation drawer (left menu)
- swipeable submenu

I am not familiar with building custom interfaces, so I am asking for some hint, guides, code samples I can learn from.

Comment: Note to the voter who give me a minus and vote to close this question, please read the question again. I am not asking for a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource. I am asking help from the community.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is similar to the Facebook app on Windows phone. 
This design concept is similar to the Navigation Drawer in Android, also known as "Hamburger menu". You can use slideview package to achieve this. Download the package from https://slideview.codeplex.com/